# How to get shareable links for edit and view on the subfolder in Google drive?

Tags: google-docs, sharing

I am in the situation, where I want to provide a link (obtained via Share option) to view all the project (i.e. folder structure with files inside). This is working without any problem. Now, I want to also provide a link to edit the particular subfolder. Again, I got link and through it I can edit files inside the subfolder. But the problem is that if I use 1st link (the view one) I am able to edit the subfolder even though I do not have permissions to do that (I suppose permissions are given by the 2nd link).

---

root folder (view link)

- subfolder 1 (edit link; can edit with the view link)

  - file 1
  - file 2
- subfolder 2

  - file 3
  - file 4

---

Is it a feature or I am doing something wrong?

Thank you,
Jirka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found an answer here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/fpxbFbxj2SQ.

According to that post it is not possible to have multiple share links with different permissions. The only option is to use email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the "Share..." pop-up menu option, not the "Get sharable link"  option; on the next dialog click on "advanced":

[image: Share... option]

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. I meant Share... option. Does it work for you?